# Object become "non object" when trying to access methods or properties

Tags: php, yii

I'm having some trouble trying to write a plugin for CraftCMS (a CMS based on YII Framework). I'm trying to create a simple fieldtype that I'm going to use inside a matrix block.
So far the public funciton getInputHtml of my fieldtype class, contains only  a

```
var_dump($this->element)
```

And it shows me, as expected:

```
object(Craft\MatrixBlockModel)#1121 (25) {
  ["elementType":protected]=&gt;
  string(11) "MatrixBlock" [.......]
```

The problem is that, as I try to change the previous

```
var_dump($this->element)
```

with a

```
var_dump($this->element->getOwner())
```

(or any other method/property of the MatrixBlockModel class), I obtain:

"Call to a member function getOwner() on a non-object"

The only think I thought is that it could have something to do with the magic method __call() overwritten in a class from which MatrixBlockModel inherit (actually, a parent of a parent of a parent...). But, trying to have a look to its code, it do not seem so.

Comment: I am not sure but it can be var_dump($this->element->getOwner)

Comment: No... thanks. getOwner() is, for sure, a method. And, anyway, also if I try to call it as a property, or if I call a method or a property that does not exist for thi class, I don't obtain a "property/method not defined" error... I still obtain "Call to a member function xxx on a non object" or "Trying to get property of non-object"... The strange thing is that with a var_dump of $this->element, it shows me that it is an object (a MatrixBlockModel, as expected)...

Answer (score 0):

It likely is something with __call as you suggest.  What happens if you do:

```
$var = $this->element;
var_dump($var);
var_dump($var->getOwner());
```

I have a hunch that if you assign it to a temporary variable that might solve the issue.